# How to get facets in drupal viewfield module?

Tags: 7, views

I am using the drupal viewfield module (http://drupal.org/project/viewfield) to show a view as a field in a node. When i have tried it, the content is showed fine but it does not show the facets present in the view.

The facets are generated from apachesolr_views module

Did the module work for anyone else for displaying facets in a view ?

Thank you